# ReactJS app doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, debugging, reactjs, mobile, web

I deployed my app to heroku, and it works perfectly on desktop, but it seems like bundle.js doesn't start on mobile, it stacks on preloader.
I used React + Redux, react-router. fetch requests I have replaced with axios, but it still doesn't work. Who has such an experience or knows how to debug website on mobile, get console logs?

### Update

also doesn't work in Firefox. It logs that 'r' in undefined in minimized script. seems like webpack do something wrong in minimizing. suspiciously works in chrome...

### Update 2

Don't forget to delete redux dev debugger when deploying your apps :)

Comment: which mobile browser are you using?

Comment: chrome for android

Comment: @azium here is the [link](https://reactmovies.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 9):

It looks like your app breaks in browsers that don't have "Redux DevTools Extension" installed.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#12-advanced-store-setup) your store setup should look like this:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(reducer, preloadedState, composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
));
```

In your code you are not using the customised `compose` function returned from the extension.